# R rename columns by using third table

Tags: r, foreign-keys, multiple-columns, rename

My problem:
Ive got 3 tables: 2 with obs. and variables.
The variables of those two tables have diffenrent names, but describe the same thing. So I want to rename the variables in one table, to than merge them together without doubleing the amount of variables.
The third table is a table which contains the names of both variables, always the two matchings in a row.

How can I rename on tables variables using table #3?
Or else can I join/merge them directly using table #3

Comment: This reads like one of those "Mary has 4 sisters. Jane is 5 years younger than half Jenny's age".  Can you provide the tables and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I've got this.  You have two dataframes; call them `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    one   = 1:10,
    two   = 1:10,
    three = 1:10
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    third  = 1:10,
    second = 1:10,
    first  = 1:10
)
```

They have variables that represent the same thing, but are named differently.  So for example "one" corresponds to "first".

You also have a third dataframe that "maps" the names together, like this:

```
dfnames <- data.frame(
    a = c("one",   "two",    "three"),
    b = c("first", "second", "third"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

And your goal is to change the names in, say, `df2` to match the names in `df1` using that mapping dataframe.  Here's one way:

```
names(df2) <- dfnames$a[match(names(df2), dfnames$b)]
```

---

Suppose now that `df2` has an extra column ("forth") that you want to keep, but that is *not* listed in `dfnames`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
    fourth = 1:10,
    third  = 1:10,
    second = 1:10,
    first  = 1:10
)
```

Then we can do:

```
newnames <- dfnames$a[match(names(df2), dfnames$b)]
names(df2) <- ifelse(is.na(newnames), names(df2), newnames)
```

Comment: Yeah you got it. Your answer worked, but there were columns in the df which had no connection to the dfnames df. Those names are gone now. How can I keep them?

Comment: See my addition above

Comment: first of all thanks! Unfortunaly its still not working. now the extra columns will stay, but the names of the matching columns changed to some numbers and not to the new names.

Comment: You are welcome to email me (see my profile page).  Include your data and if necessary a brief description of the expected output and I'll see if I can get the code working for you.